# Extending my style with Material styles in Angular

Tags: angular, material-ui

I have a html label in the webpage which should look like a button in Material.

I have tried the following

```
@use "@angular/material/theming" as material;

.likematbutton {
margin-right: 10px;
@extend .mdc-button !optional;
```

but it doesn't work well, no any change in the outlook of the label.

My question is how can I reuse the Material styling in scss level ?

Thanks in advance.

Csaba